# How to deploy war and client on remote Tomcat using gradle?

Tags: tomcat, gradle

I would like to:
1. stop tomcat server on remote machine (Windows Server 2012)
2. delete/clean war on the server (from webapps tomcat folder)
3. deploy war file on Tomcat (copy it in webapps tomcat folder)
4. copy client jar file and jnlp file into webapps tomcat folder
5. start Tomcat

My idea is to use ftp for copying files (I have enabled this on Windows Server 2012). But I don't know how to do this using gradle? And it leaves unknown to me how to stop/start Tomcat server?

What is recommanded way to do this with gradle?

Thnaks in advance.
Best regards,
mismas

Comment: Is that plugin helpful: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin ?

Comment: It says "This plugin also can't deploy a WAR file to a remote container" and to use Cargo plugin instead. But I don't understand how based on the given examples ... Could you please direct me a litlle bit. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the configuration should be passed via `cargo` extension.

Comment: I don't understand how. Can you clarify it? Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the cargo plugin. https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin

Comment: @MarkVieira I did and it is not quite clear to me. This is what I have tried: `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.0.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'
cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat6x'
    port = 8080
 def warPath = '/dist/server/MyApp-' + versionName + '/MyApp-' + versionName + '.war'
    deployable {
        file = file(warPath)
        context = 'MyApp-' + versionName
    }
    remote {
        hostname = 'IPAddres'
        username = 'admin'
        password = 'secretPass'
    }
}`

Comment: And I get an error: `18:05:05.350 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [D:\workspaces\workspace\Project\dist\server\MyApp-TEST-ACS42.1\MyApp-ACS42.1.war]`  So, could you please give an example how to use this plugin to do those 5 tasks I listed in my question. I am not aware what am I doing wrong ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce the problem, that's why you're not getting the answer. Run gradle with `-s` and `-d` switches to see what the problem might be.

Comment: @Opal This is the error when I run cargoDeployRemote -s `Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username and password you provided are not correct (error 401)`

Comment: @Opal I have no problems with connecting on the server, where Tomcat is installed, with the same credentials using mstsc (MS remote desktop). Username is in this format: SRV-SOMETHING\Administrator.

Comment: @Opal please help, any idea what could went wrong? I think that username and password are ought to be the ones used for connecting on remote server where Tomcat is installed. Am I right about it?

Comment: @Opal how does this plugin know where is Tomcat installed on the remote server?

Comment: @mismas, sorry I don't know because I've never used that plugin. Also I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to log in with username: tomcat, password: tomcat (not the credentials used when connecting through remote desktop - mstsc). Plus I had to add manager-script role to tomcat user in tomcat-users.xml file, in order to resolve exception "The username you provided is not allowed to use the text-based Tomcat Manager (error 403)".